# Need help in multiple automation on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a few automation that I'd like to include in my google sheets to make my work easier.

So I have a table full of video info with 2 columns that will have to manually insert as my daily report.

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLPRc.png)

The sixth and last column is originally empty and I would have to key in the result based on a video recordings online. What I would like to make automatically is the last column to show "Video Completed" and "Incomplete Video" based on condition / criteria. "Video Completed" is videos that are at least 30 minutes long and "Incomplete Video" is anything below.

For the sixth column, I would like to change the duration from 1:30 to 90m or 1:30:30 to 90m 30s. For this column is not a priority as every video timing will be different and will still need to key in manually.

Another one is, there is  small table that I need to sum up based on criteria. In this case, the sum of "Video Deleted" from the last column is calculated by the sum of "Video Deleted" in a range of different clusters eg, "AEE, EDE, EEE", etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

> change the duration from 1:30 to 90m or 1:30:30 to 90m 30s.

if the time is valid use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1:A2, "[mm]\m ss\s"), " 00s", ))
```

[image]

validity can be checked with the secret formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISTIME_STRICT(A1:A2))
```

[image]